# macOS Monterey - How to change port on which Airplay receiver is running

Tags: macos, airplay, macos-monterey

The issue about busy ports (5000 or 7000) on macOS Monterey is quite common for developers now. All the solutions on the internet suggest turning off the Airplay receiver (from System Preferences > Sharing > Toggle Airplay Receiver)

But I love the Airplay feature and use it quite heavily and I don't want to turn it off.

So Is there any way to change the port on which Airplay Receiver is running, Is there any configuration file or something like that to change the port?

Comment: Any sensible system - & I would assume Apple to be reasonably competent in that regard - will just increment port numbers until it finds one that's not busy. This should in practise be a non-issue.